# How to shallow copy pointer to vector?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to shallow copy pointer to vector?
Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> foo = {"apple", "melon", "kiwi"};
    std::string *argv = foo.data();
    size_t argc = foo.size();

    std::vector<std::string> boo(argv, argv+argc);
}
```

Does `boo` gets shallow copied?

Is it faster to initialize `boo` than doing `std::vector<std::string> boo(foo);`?

Comment: Standard containers don't shallow copy.  They "Do the right thing".

Comment: Its a vector of strings, not a vector of pointers to strings. You can't __not__ copy the strings.

Comment: you can use shared_ptr<vector<string>>

Comment: @AndrewKashpur Do you mind posting an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::vector` has unique ownership of its own buffer. The buffer cannot be shared with other vectors. As such, the `std::vector` class does not provide a way to "shallow copy", except in case of transferring the ownership to another `std::vector`, in which case the source `std::vector` will no longer own the transferred buffer. Such transfer of ownership occurs in a move constructor or move assignment operator.

Other container implementations than the standard `std::vector` have been written , which do implement "copy on write" semantics, which do not copy elements until a copy is modified.

`std::vector<std::string> boo(argv, argv+argc)` copies the elements in the range, as per documentation of vector. It is not faster than copying the vector directly.

It is possible to refer to an object using indirection, such as reference or a (possibly smart) pointer. For example, you could write `std::vector<std::string>& boo = foo;` in which case no copying of elements occurs.

When referring to objects indirectly, you must be very careful to ensure that the lifetime of the referred object is at least as long as the reference is used. If the lifetime of the object ends while a reference still exists, that reference is said to be dangling. The behaviour of attempting to access an object through a dangling reference is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

if you want shallow copy of something you can use `std::shared_ptr`. Short example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include<vector>

typedef std::vector<std::string> string_vector;

int main() {
  std::shared_ptr<string_vector> s_ptr = std::make_shared<string_vector>( string_vector({"a","b"}) );
  auto s_ptr_2 = s_ptr;
  (*s_ptr_2)[0] = "c";
  std::cout<<(*s_ptr)[0]<<" "<<(*s_ptr)[1] <<std::endl;
  std::cout<<(*s_ptr_2)[0]<<" "<<(*s_ptr_2)[1] <<std::endl;
}
```

I advise you to read about `shared_ptr` before using it (lifetime, ownership of objects)

Answer (score 1):

By my understanding, you want `vector` boo to contain what is inside foo without actually copying any of the data? in which case you have two options.

In the first instance you can do as eerorika suggested and make boo a reference to foo, essentially the same as a pointer. I don't think this is quite what you were going for though.

```
std::vector<std::string> & boo = foo;
```

Alternatively you can use `std::move` which will set boo's internal pointer to point at foo's elements and then set foo's to `nullptr`. this will put foo in an unsafe state to use however so don't make any calls to it after doing this.

```
std::vector<std::string> boo(std::move(foo));
```

Comment: I think `std::vector` in particular has some guarantees in the standard about its state post-move.  But in general that is definitely sound advice.  Post-move objects are only suitable for being re-assigned-to, or for destruction.